# no implicit conversion of nil into String during update rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update password. Here is my form

```
<%= form_for(:profile, url: {action: 'change_password'}, remote: true ) do |f| %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
def change_password
    @customer = Customer.find session[:customer_id]
    unless params[:profile].nil?
      password = params[:password]
      @customer.update_attribute(:password, password)
    end
  end
```

During registration I have encrypted and saved my password. Here is the model I have

```
def self.generate_hash password
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest password   #Showing error in this line
    end

    def generate_password
        self.password = Customer.generate_hash self.password
    end
```

But while updating the password getting error as

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def self.generate_hash password
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest password.to_s   #Showing error in this line
end
```

**Update**

Try replacing

```
password = params[:password]
```

by

```
password = params[:profile][:password]
```

This may be causing password to hold nil.

Comment: after updating I think password updated but I am unable to login

Comment: Yes password is updated but once I logout and login I am unable to login

Comment: Then you should check why *password* in `self.generate_hash password` is blank while generating hash.